# How do I write a custom command in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

I want to write a command for Atom that composes two or more pre-existing commands, like "Select Line" and then "Cut". How do I do that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can add the following code to your `init.coffee` file:

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor', 'custom:cut-line', ->
  editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()
  editor.selectLinesContainingCursors()
  editor.cutSelectedText()
```

You can get the code to execute from the source by searching for strings in the command palette. And once you have a command created, you can map a key to it by editing your `keymap.cson` file:

```
'atom-text-editor':
    'alt-cmd-z': 'custom:cut-line'
```

Comment: I found the code for the commands in atom/src/[register-default-commands.coffee](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/f376316d60b7b0e96ceaff8c631ea6458f31907c/src/register-default-commands.coffee)

Comment: I want to do a composed command using installed packages. How do I go about using non-editor commands?

Comment: @Erich maybe this answer will help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/27230783/6426778

Comment: @Lee Any idea how to call it from the context menu?