# Use the tree-view in Atom editor init script

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor

I'm trying to write a init script for the Atom editor to add a custom command to be able to reveal the currently opened editor file in the tree-view with one key combination, instead of two.

Here is an example code (which makes something different) to make clear how it generally has to look like.

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-editor', 'custom:cut-line', ->
  editor = atom.workspace.getActiveEditor()
  editor.selectLine()
  editor.cutSelectedText()
```

The two commands I need should not be sent to the `editor`, but to the `tree-view`. Here are the two commands:

```
  tree-view:toggle-focus
  tree-view:reveal-active-file
```

I assume I have to do something similar as above, like `getActiveTreeView` or something like that. I tried to google it but it doesn't seem to be obvious. Does someone know how to do this?

It could look something like this:

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-editor', 'custom:show-active-file', ->
  tree-view.toggle-focus()
  tree-view.reveal-active-file()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `atom.commands.dispatch()` method to send a command when getting a hold of the object to send the commands to is hard. In your case, you can use:

```coffee
atom.commands.add 'atom-editor', 'custom:show-active-file', ->
  atom.commands.dispatch(atom.workspaceView.element, 'tree-view:toggle-focus')
  atom.commands.dispatch(atom.workspaceView.element, 'tree-view:reveal-active-file')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I copy the code into my init.coffe and restart Atom, the `custom:show-active-file` wont show up in my keybinding settings, though.

Comment: I'm not sure if you got a notification @Lee

Comment: When I just bind a key to the `custom:show-active-file` command, the key resolver debugger window (cmd-.) shows a green line. But nothing really hapens.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Lee's answer is not correct anymore. Within changes in the API the changed the naming of `atom.workspaceView` to `atom.workspace`.

So, if anyone gets here (sure questions and answer is a "bit" old), here's the current working script.

```coffee
atom.commands.add 'atom-editor', 'custom:show-active-file', ->
atom.commands.dispatch(atom.workspace.element, 'tree-view:toggle-focus')
atom.commands.dispatch(atom.workspace.element, 'tree-view:reveal-active-file')
```

@Source
https://discuss.atom.io/t/workspaceview-events/14595/4