# Atom Editor Auto Indent Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: keymapping, atom-editor

I followed along with the discussion in this question: [Auto indent code in Atom editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611377/auto-indent-code-in-atom-editor) but couldn't get mine to work. :(

I have this in my `keymap.cson` file:

`'.editor':
  'ctrl-i': 'window:toggle-invisibles'
  'ctrl-t': 'editor:toggle-indent-guide'
  'ctrl-v': 'tree-view:toggle'
  'ctrl-l': 'go-to-line:toggle'
  'cmd-shift-[': 'editor:auto-indent'`

The other keyboard command work, but `'cmd-shift-[': 'editor:auto-indent'` does not. Each of the indented options has exactly 2 spaces in front of them. `'.editor'` has none.

What did I get wrong?

Comment: have you tried 'ctrl-shift-[' ?

Comment: No, I never did. And Atom is such a mess now I've put it away for a while. At least until version 1.0. Thanks for the thought; I'll file it away for when I try Atom again.