# Is it possible to align code in Atom IDE?

Tags: ide, alignment, atom-editor

## I have

[image]

## Goal

I'm trying to align a block of code base on `=`.

[image]

How would one go about doing this in Atom IDE?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is an [`atom-alignment`](https://atom.io/packages/atom-alignment) package.

Answer (score 2):

Try one of these plugins:

1. https://atom.io/packages/alignment
2. https://atom.io/packages/atom-alignment

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611377/how-to-auto-indent-code-in-the-atom-editor) related question may help.

Comment: Plugin 1 was last updated in 2015.  Plugin 2 has an order of magnitude more downloads and stars.