# Atom auto indent after tag/bracket close

Tags: php, html, tags, atom-editor, brackets

Is there a way (or package) to auto-indent content inside tags/brackets after I type the closing tag. The default Atom `bracket matcher` only indents correctly if nothing is in between the brackets.

**What happens:**

[image]

**What I want to happen:**

[image]

Same goes for closing `HTML` tags.

There is [an auto-indenting option within Atom](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22661340/7356355), but I want it to happen automatically when typing the closing tag. PHPStorm does this perfectly.

Is there a setting/package that does this?

Comment: look at :https://stackoverflow.com/a/22661340/7356355

Comment: I want it to auto indent automatically after typing a closing tag. PHPStorm does this very well.

Comment: try: https://atom.io/packages/smart-indent

Comment: It doesn't do the thing I want